# Jupyter: Write a custom magic that modifies the contents of the cell it's in

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In a Jupyter notebook there are some built-in magics that change the contents of a notebook cell. For example, the `%load` magic replaces the contents of the current cell with the contents of a file on the file system.

How can I write a custom magic command that does something similar?

What I have so far prints something to stdout

```
def tutorial_asset(line):
    print('hello world')


def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    ipython.register_magic_function(tutorial_asset, 'line')
```

And I can load it with `%load_ext tutorial_asset`. But from there I'm lost.

[Edit]:

I've found a way to get to the interactive shell instance:

```
  @magics_class
  class MyMagics(Magics):

      @line_magic
      def tutorial_asset(self, parameters):
          self.shell
```

The `self.shell` object seems to give complete access to the set of cells in the notebook, but the only way I can find to modify the cells is to do `self.shell.set_next_input('print("hello world")')`. This isn't sufficient because, in a Jupyter notebook, that input cell is skipped, and it doesn't overwrite the input cell, it instead creates a new input cell after it.

This would be fine, but if I run the notebook a second time, it creates another input cell with the same file loaded, which is annoying. Can I have it load only once, say, by checking if the contents are already in the next cell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***EDIT**: After a little further digging, I found that the current build of notebook cannot do both.*

Well, this is a little tricky...  Looking at the IPython code, it looks like you need to use `set_next_input` if you want to replace the cell, and `run_cell` if you actually want to run some code.  However, I can't get both to work at once - it looks like `set_next_input` always wins.

Digging into the code, the web front-end supports [optional clearing of the output](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/static/notebook/js/notebook.js#L206-L208) on `set_next_input`.  However, the [kernel doesn't yet support setting this flag](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/master/ipykernel/zmqshell.py#L528-L536) (and so output will always be cleared as the default action).  To do better will require a patch to ipykernel.

The best I therefore have is the following code, using jupyter notebook version 4.2.1:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.core.magic import Magics, magics_class, line_magic

@magics_class
class MyMagics(Magics):

    @line_magic
    def lmagic(self, line):
        "Replace current line with new output"
        raw_code = 'print("Hello world!")'
        # Comment out this line if you actually want to run the code.
        self.shell.set_next_input('# %lmagic\n{}'.format(raw_code), replace=True)
        # Uncomment this line if you want to run the code instead.
        # self.shell.run_cell(raw_code, store_history=False)
        
ip = get_ipython()
ip.register_magics(MyMagics)
```

This gives you a magic command `lmagic` that will either replace the current cell or run the `raw_code` depending on which bit of the code you have commented out.

Comment: This technique is creating a new cell for me instead of modifying the current cell. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ajp619 It's quite an old comment, but anyway, it's replacing because of the `replace=True` bit. If you change it to False it'll create a new cell.

Comment: Jupyter Notebook v6.4.0 still only does one at a time, but Jupyter Lab v3.0.16 can both replace and run at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `cell_magic` for that:

```py
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.core.magic import Magics, cell_magic, magics_class
from IPython.core import magic_arguments

@magics_class
class MyMagic(Magics):
    @cell_magic
    def my_magic(self, line, cell):
        new_cell = cell + "\n" + "print('World')"
        self.shell.run_cell(new_cell)

ipy = get_ipython()
ipy.register_magics(MyMagic)
```

```py
%%my_magic
print("Hello")
```

```
Hello
World
```